# admin and user session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want to save user and admin sessions in different paths how can i do that in codeigniter.

I want to do that because if i login on the admin side the front end user gets logged in automatically.

I cannot user different sessions now as i will have to make changes at all the places.

I tried

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],       PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';

if (isset($segments[1]) && $segments[1] == 'admin')  {

$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'admin_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1440; 
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache/session/admin/';

} else {

$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'catalog_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache/session/catalog/';

}

$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

The above code redirects admin the the login page on click of any of the links after logging in

How can it be done..

Comment: better show how you set the sessions for admin and client

Comment: You might be able to use [Session Array](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) and store information you need.

Answer (score 0):

My simple  suggestion is to create 2 flag fields in session which will set at process of admin login and front end login.
you can put any put any logic in your code by twiking these 2 flag fields values.
I hope this answer helps you.